# How to plot manually points in Python charts (hold on function in Matlab)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot manually points in python charts. This should be the hold on function in Matlab.

MWE

```
#-- Input values
time = 3
tau_1= 0.5
tau_2= 0.02
#-- Plot
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, tau_1, "--mo")
plt.plot(time, tau_2, "--co" )
plt.ylabel("tau",color="black",fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("time", fontsize=14) 
plt.grid() 

#-- Change the Input manually after seeing the results
```

Python should plot in the same chart the input values at each manual change of the input. I want to underline that I specifically want this solution, where the user run the program, and change manually the input  values

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misunderstood your question in my earlier answer. It looks like you want to run the same code over and over by just changing the inputs, not rewrite the new inputs again in the script.

One approach is to save the plotted figure to a pickle file. Then unpickle it to plot the new inputs.

```
import os
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#-- Input values
time = 2
tau_1= 0.8
tau_2= 0.03

# If replotting, use the saved figure
if os.path.isfile('myplot.pickle'):
    with open('myplot.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        fig, ax = pickle.load(f)
        print('here')
else:  # Create a new one
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(time, tau_1, "--mo")
ax.plot(time, tau_2, "--co" )
ax.set_ylabel("tau",color="black",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("time", fontsize=14) 
ax.grid()

# Save the plotted figure and axes to a pickle file
with open('myplot.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((fig, ax), f)
```

Keep changing the inputs values on top and run it again. It will plot to the same figure.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, perhaps my MWE was not well explained. Once I run the code once, I just want to change manually the input values, run it again and find in the same chart the points that I want.

Comment: I understood that from your comment in Klops answer. So changed my answer. You have to save your figure somewhere, then plot to the same figure. Here I am saving it to a pickle file.

Comment: Hi, it works but it keeps in the memory everything. I try by deleting all the images and resetting all the variables in the Kernel but it keeps everything in the memory. How would it be possible to reset it?

Comment: Hi, I fixed, thanks, I delete the file mypicke file in the folder!! Many thanks for solving my issue

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple: avoid creating a new figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#-- Input values
time = 3
tau_1= 0.5
tau_2= 0.02
#-- Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()  # reference to chart

ax.plot(time, tau_1, "--mo")
ax.plot(time, tau_2, "--co" )
ax.set_ylabel("tau",color="black",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("time", fontsize=14) 
ax.grid() 

#-- New Input, added manually after seeing the results
time = 2
tau_1= 0.8
tau_2= 0.01

#-- Plot
# line with new figure removed
ax.plot(time, tau_1, "--mo")
ax.plot(time, tau_2, "--co" )
ax.set_ylabel("tau",color="black",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("time", fontsize=14) 
ax.grid()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but it s not what I want. ´´time = 2
tau_1= 0.5
tau_2= 0.02
#-- Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()  # reference to chart

ax.plot(time, tau_1, "--mo")
ax.plot(time, tau_2, "--co" )
ax.set_ylabel("tau",color="black",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("time", fontsize=14) 
ax.grid()´´´´Once you run this code, I just want to change the input values and run again and plot on the same chart the points